# How to make control that is Hidden by default show up in the Visual Studio 2010 WPF designer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a control that has Hidden visibility because it is bound to a property in the View Model whose default value causes it to be hidden.  I can access it through the XAML but I'd like it still shown in the designer.

Is there a clean way of doing this?  For now, I'm manually editing the Visibility attribute to make it show up, but I'd rather not have to do that, in case I forget to change it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it is a lot cleaner but you should set it to Visible in the ctor (before the Initialize);

Comment: Care to explain down vote on a accepted answer two years old?

Comment: It's not me who down voted. But I can't understand how your answer could possibly help. I don't think the designer reads the code behind file at all?

Comment: @Arek Exactly designer does not read the code behind and it has the check mark.

Comment: okay, then how setting anything in the constructor would make hidden control visible in the designer?

Answer (score 5):

You can bind to the boolean attached property `DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode`, which is true only if you are inside the designer. Here is an example:

```
<Window x:Class="Visitest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=PresentationFramework" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="conv"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Margin="8" Background="Green" 
                 Visibility="{Binding (cm:DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource conv}}"/>           
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I clarified my question a bit.  The Visibility is already bound to an item in the View Model, whose default value causes it to be hidden.  Maybe I could change the binding to what you have here in the constructor if I'm in Design Mode?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Hide WPF elements in Visual Studio designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322520/hide-wpf-elements-in-visual-studio-designer)?  It looks like other people solved the issue by creating a simple custom extension.

Comment: No, I have not seen that link before.  I'll check it out, thanks.