# C# Hide controls in form in designer mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have a webBrowser that takes up full screen but when a user clicks on a certain button, the webBrowser hides and the the user is able to see the items behind the webBrowser.

How can I make it so that I am able to see the items behind the webBrowser without actually hiding the webBrowser or sending it to back in the designer.

For example, is there a way to right click and make invisible a form only during designer mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide WPF elements in Visual Studio designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322520/hide-wpf-elements-in-visual-studio-designer)

Comment: Context menu (Right mouse click) `Send to back` in WinForms designer

Comment: The easy way is to design the `WebBrowser` control with a very small size, and blow it up to full screen on the form's constructor right after the `InitializeControls()` call is completed

Comment: Another possibility would be to change your program design so the WebBrowser is on a separate form/window that gets launched when it is needed.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I'm gonna go with your answer! Feel free to post it as a legit answer and I'll checkmark it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting design mode from a Control's constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166226/detecting-design-mode-from-a-controls-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Every WebBrowser inherits from System.ComponentModel.Component. Components have readonly field DesignMode which states if current component is in design mode.

You can use it e.g. this way (I don't see Your code so I am imaging). Just be sure to add this code in Your designer class

```
if (webBrowser.DesignMode)
{
    webBrowser.Visible = false;
}
```

WebBrowser Class

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Component.DesignMode Property

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to design the WebBrowser control with a very small size, and blow it up to full screen on the form's constructor right after the `InitializeControls()` call is completed.