# WPF set default Visibility value when editing

Tags: wpf, default, visibility

I have Visibility bound to a bool, which works perfectly. However when editing the page the Border is not visible.  I have to delete the Visibility Binding, make my changes and redo the Visibility Binding.

I'm pretty sure I saw there is a way to set a "editing default", but I cannot find that link anymore (or remember what it was called). Can someone explain how to set the default to visible so I can see it whilst editing, but not affect it's operation at runtime?

```
<Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="HotPink" BorderThickness="2" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" 
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=GenerateWorkOrders, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <Label Content="Not Visible While Editing"/>
        </Border>
```

Comment: by 'editing the page', did you mean when you are using Designer in Visual Studio? You may want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278611/587690)

Comment: Generateworkorders is presumably unchecked by default. You could maybe set it checked or give it's ischecked a fallbackvalue value of true.

Comment: Yes Designer mode in VS and I believe FallbackValue is what I was looking for, but this doesn't seem to do anything:  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=GenerateWorkOrders, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=Visible}" . Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you try `TargetNullValue` ?

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but it looks interesting. Can you show how to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default value of `IsChecked` of GenerateWorkOrders `CheckBox` is `false`

If `IsChecked` have `Binding`, you can use `FallbackValue`:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="GenerateWorkOrders" IsChecked="{Binding SomeProperty, FallbackValue=True}" />
```

Another way is to avoid the binding, you can use the `DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode` Attached Properties that indicate if you in design mode ([More inforamtion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode?view=netframework-4.8)).

You can use this property in behavior, or in XAML only approach:

```
    <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="HotPink" BorderThickness="2" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ElementName=GenerateWorkOrders, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(componentModel:DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode)}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Label Content="Not Visible While Editing"/>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Thank you! I put the FallbackValue on the wrong control... Instead of putting it on the checkbox (like you show) I was trying to put a FallbackValue in the Visibility property of the Border.